# ASP.NET Core 7 Web API : Options method 405 not allowed

Tags: asp.net-core, cors, asp.net-core-webapi, react-query

I have an ASP.NET Core 7 Web API project, in which I have written this method:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost("requestcode")]
public async Task<ActionResult> RequestCode(RequestCodeDTO request)
```

Now, in `Program.cs`, I have set up CORS to allow all:

```
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader();
    });
});
```

And later:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
            
app.UseCors();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

I call this method from a React query mutation function, which seems to automatically call options on page load. But this fails with a 405 error.

All fixes to this I've seen is to enable CORS (allow all methods) but I've done that, and it's not worked. The Post method CAN be called, so it's not CORS entirely that fails. Just the options call.

Does anybody know why?

Comment: Quoting MDN: _"In response, the server returns a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header with Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, which means that the resource can be accessed by any origin."_. Check your response and if there's no such result, then your CORS is misconfigured.

Comment: Order matters. Move `app.UseCors();` before `app.UseAuthentication();`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#middleware-order

Comment: Yes, try use Cors at the beginning of pipeline.